# How to deal with Result<T,E> inside the closure function in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a nested object in mongodb that I want to deserialize/decode back into a struct.
Here's the structure :

```
pub struct ItemUnit {
    /// unit's name like PCS, DOZEN, PACK, etc
    pub name: String,

    /// denote this unit value
    pub multiplier: f64,

    /// item's price in this unit
    pub price: Option<f64>,
}

pub struct Item {
    /// item's name
    pub name: String,

    /// available unit types available for this item, in an array format
    pub units: Vec<ItemUnit>,
}
```

as you can see the struct is nested and `units` is an array (`Vec<ItemUnit>`).

As Rust have a culture of "*not letting you go with error possibility*", this quickly becomes tricky. In Rust mongodb driver, you have to deserialize/decode them back from 'bson' document into "native type" such as String, f64, and so on. Each deserialize operation returns `Result<>` since there's a possibility of error in it.

I have a problem with nested object with an array of another object in it:

```
// doc is the data from a single `Item`
// since `get_array` might throw a ValueAccess error, I map it into my own custom Error type
// so `units_bson` is now a `Vec<mongodb::bson::Bson>` type
let units_bson = doc.get_array("units").map_err(Self::map_mongodb_err)?;

// in the next step, I need to decode the mongodb::bson::Bson for each element in this array
/// here's I use map() with closure
let units: Vec<ItemUnit> = units_bson.iter().map(|u| { 
   
   // get_str() returns Result<T,E> but since ItemUnit only accepts a string not Result<> type
   // I had to handle the error possibilities here in the closure/map function
   // but the ? operator only available on a function that returns `Result` or `Option` 
   //  (or another type that implements `Try`)
   let name = u.as_document().unwrap().get_str("name").map_err(Self::map_mongodb_err);
   return ItemUnit { name, multiplier, p_buy };

}).collect();
```

So my question is how do you catch an error inside a closure?

Or is there any other workaround like try-catch block that can also catch any error inside a closure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is propagate the error into the `Vec`.

```
units_bson.iter().map(|u| {
  // This question-mark returns from the closure, not the whole function.
  let name = code_and_stuff.map_err(...)?;
  // We're returning Result values now, so wrap the value in Ok.
  Ok(ItemUnit { name, ... })
});
```

At this point, we have an iterator over values of type `Result<ItemUnit, SomeError>`. If we were to call `collect` now, naively we might expect to get a `Vec<Result<ItemUnit, SomeError>>`, and indeed that is one correct result. But we can also request a `Result<Vec<ItemUnit>, SomeError>`, because `Result<A, E>` has a [`FromIterator` instance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA%2C%20E%3E%3E) for this exact use case.

```
units_bson.iter().map(|u| {
  // This question-mark returns from the closure, not the whole function.
  let name = code_and_stuff.map_err(...)?;
  // We're returning Result values now, so wrap the value in Ok.
  Ok(ItemUnit { name, ... })
}).collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?;
```

Then, with one more question mark after our `collect` call, we propagate the error to our outer function's result.

Welcome to the wonderful world of Rust error values. I promise this sort of thing becomes second nature the more you do it; you won't even notice yourself adding the little question marks in a handful of places.

Comment: This is a correct answer and my code works now, but I still don't understand what exactly happen here. Why does `<Vec<_>, _>>`  not having the same number of `<` bracket ? Would you mind to give us some link or further references ? It's not that clear from Rust manual

Comment: `collect` takes a type argument, which we're specifying explicitly since it would confuse Rust otherwise (the type argument in `collect` and the one in `?` would effectively "cancel off" and cannot be inferred). The type argument we specify is `Result<Vec<_>, _>`. I could've written it out in full `Result<Vec<ItemUnit>, SomeError>`, but the type I wrote was enough to disambiguate for the compiler. The number of angled brackets in my example lines up.

Comment: OK. so `Result<Vec<_>, _>` is abbreviation from `Result<Vec<ItemUnit>, SomeError>`. Thank you for such clear and cut explanation.